# realm object server version

Tags: realm, version

I have admin access to a realm object server.  I know I can use the version command to see what is installed.  How can I determine if if is the developer vs enterprise version?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `ros --version`? It is running *somewhere*. If you can't do that and you have a web UI and stuff, it's probably `1.x` see https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/1.0 for docs on that

Comment: Yes - that only tells me the version number - no the edition - IE - Developer vs Enterprise

Comment: I think the ROS is the same in both cases, and the question is whether the client sends a "feature token".